# Replace an Object by another type of Object in a Main[JAVA]

Tags: java, object

i try to to change a Object to another type of Object in my main. Here is some code to see what i actually mean.

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller newcontroller = Controller.create();
        newcontroller.change();
    }
}
```

Controler.java:

```
public class Controller{

    public static Controller create() {
        return new North(0,0);
    }

    public void change() {
    }

}
```

North.java:

```
public class North extends Controller{
    int x;
    int y;

    public North(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void change() {
        super.change();
        //Now i have to replace the newcontroller North(x,y) by South(x,y)
        super.newcontroller = new South(this.x, this.y)
    }
}
```

South.java is just like the North one but it changes to North again.
How can i do that? Or am i doing it completly on a false way?
its not allowed to use if, switch, for, while, ... Only linear programming

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to have a boolean flag inside the Controller class and check the flag to change, but this should not be done because it doesn't follow OOP principles. In your code above it looks like you are creating a Factory that returns a controller.

```
public class ControllerFactory {

    public static CreateController(boolean isNorth) {
        return isNorth ? new North() : new South(); 
    }
}
```

And wherever you instantiate Controller have a boolean that holds the current state of the controller.

```
boolean isNorth = true;

isNorth = !isNorth;
controller = ControllerFactory.CreateController(isNorth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a little modification.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Controller ctl = Controller.create();
    ctl.change();
}
```

}

```
public class Controller{

public static Controller create() {
    return new North(0,0);
}

public Controller change() {
    return null;
}
```

}

```
public class North extends Controller{
int x;
int y;

public North(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public Controller change() {
    return new South(this.x, this.y);
}
```

}

```
public class South extends Controller {
int x;
int y;

public South(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public Controller change() {
    return new North(this.x, this.y);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, this unfortunately doesnt work for me. To get this working i need to make changes in the Main Class. And this is not allowed in this task. I need to do something like ctl = ctl.change() in order to change from North to South. Maybe i am missing here something :-(

Comment: Why do you need to change your main class. I just added return type for change() method.